# Loading `UIImage` inside `UItableViewCell` not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, uiimage

I have read many questions and answers [here or on the web] through this day and I can't find an answer to my problem.

The situation is :

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UIImageView`, 
I load the content of the cell from a server and this is working as expected.
for the `UIImageView` I started a new thread to download the image, 
but the image is not showing UNTIL I download the whole items in my DataBase !

I have tried putting a link to a sample image in the internet and this works little bit okay [ with some delay ]

The problems :
 1. The `UIImgeView` does not set its image as Until I load the whole table.
 2. The `UIActivityIndicator` stops running before loading the image.

I think I am doing one thing wrong that causes those problems.

**here is my code :**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

OfferTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OfferCell"];
cellHeight = cell.frame.size.height;


Offer  * tmpOffer = _offersArray[indexPath.row];

[cell.likeButtonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(like:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.disLikeButtonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(disLike:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//Offer Title
cell.offerTitle.text = tmpOffer.OfferTitle;

//Offer Image
[cell.offerImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
cell.offerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
if(!tmpOffer.imageLoaded){

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        UIActivityIndicatorView * indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        [cell.offerImage addSubview:indicator];
        [indicator startAnimating];
        tmpOffer.OfferImageObject =  [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tmpOffer.OfferImage]]];
        tmpOffer.imageLoaded = true;
        [indicator stopAnimating];
        [indicator removeFromSuperview];
        [cell.offerImage setImage:tmpOffer.OfferImageObject];
        cell.offerImage.clipsToBounds =YES;
        cell.offerImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        tmpOffer.imageLoaded = true;
    });
}

//Refresh the table if it shows the last cell
if(indexPath.row == _offersArray.count-1){
    UILabel * updating = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 70, 30)];
    updating.text = @"جاري التحديت ...";
#warning show updating message

    [self refresh];

}
return cell;
}
```

**and here is the refreshing method :**

```
-(void)refresh{
NSMutableString * path = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"api/Offers?$top=4&$skip="];
NSUInteger numOfElements = [_offersArray count];
NSString * strNumOfElements =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)numOfElements];
[path appendString:strNumOfElements];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)

 {
     int start = (int)_offersArray.count;



     if(mappingResult.array.count !=0){
         [_offersArray  addObjectsFromArray: [mappingResult.array mutableCopy]];
         NSMutableArray * indexesToBeReloaded = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         for(int i =start   ; i<(int)_offersArray.count;i++){
             [indexesToBeReloaded addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
         }

         [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexesToBeReloaded withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
         }
     else{
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"لا عروض جديدة الان " message: @"وصلت إلى ابق بالقرب لمتابعة أفضل العروض (:" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: @"حسناً",nil];
         [alert show];
     }
 } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.description delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: @"",nil];
     [alert show];
 }

 ];
```

}

your help is really appreciated ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to load Images inside a UITableViewCell is AFNetworking UIImageView Category class.

Import `AFNetworking` Library to your project & `UIImageView+AFNetworking` class as well.

```
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
```

Then inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Load the image as below.

```
__weak OfferTableViewCell *weakCell = cell;

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImageLink]];

        [weakCell.offerImage setImageWithURLRequest:request
                                      placeholderImage:nil
                                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                                   weakCell.offerImage.image = image;
                                                   [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
                                               } failure:nil];
```

This will do all the things for you asynchronously

Comment: You might want to cache the images or use the version of NSURLRequest which let's you control the cache underneath. Otherwise you could end up refetching the image every time you scroll.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel , I have managed that by adding *imageLoaded* attribute to the cell so it won't reload the cell.

Comment: That won't work if you scroll off and on and it reuses a  different cell for the index path. You need any cache to be outside of the cell itself in the controller or use the underlying cache NSURLRequest provides.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel You are right, it didn't work. I don't think the problem will be solved by cacheing the images as I have a count down timer in each cell and by reloading each cell when I scroll, The counter's behaviour will not be accepted, any thought about this? thanx in advance

Comment: Pretty much with tables you have to hold all state outside of the cells because of their transient nature. All the cell should do is present a view or control for the data it is a temporary custodian of.  So per row counters, image caches etc should be in the view controller or a data model that can easily be indexed by indexPath.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel Thank you for you suggestion. now it is working, following your suggestion by not manipulating the view directly but instead updating the model. Now the tableview reloads when ever it suits it as the model will keep providing valid data to be reload. thank you man <3

Answer (score 2):

All UI related work should be done in the main thread.

You should probably be doing the following:

1) Create a dictionary of images with URL as the key and the image as the value. use this to keep copies of images once loaded so you only do it once.

2) Do not do any UI updates in the background thread. Make the activity indicator a property of the cell so the cell carries it around. As cells get reused! you only need to create it once. If the cells image is in the dictionary and the activity is not nil, make sure it is removed and stopped. if you need to load the image, create the activity if needed and add it. Start the indicator BEFORE doing the background load.

3) In the background thread, only do the load of the image. When it has loaded, dispatch sync to the main thread a call to an imageLoaded method you add which takes the image as an argument and the cell indexPath the load is for. In this method, add the image to your dictionary and ask the table to reload the row at the indexPath. This time that individual cell will stop the indicator and show the images because it will follow 2).

This will ensure your cells update as images arrive and that all UI operations occur on the main thread.

You need to track which images are in progress loading so you do not have multiple running. You have this problem already I think in your current code if so somebody scrolls a cell off screen and back.

Comment: Thank you, I will consider your suggestions, I am sure many ppl will find it useful for a long time from now *thumbs up*